# In The Resistance, how does In the Spotlight work?

Tags: the-resistance

The card says "You can choose another player to submit their Mission card face up."

If 4 people are on the mission, and 1 player has this card played on them, do the other 3 players get to see what card he played before choosing the cards they will submit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The player using *In the Spotlight* must announce their intent to use it immediately after a successful *Mission Team Vote*, and they must select the target player before any team member selects their *Mission* card. After the target has been chosen, each team member selects a *Mission* card and puts it on the table in front of them. The player who is the target of *In the Spotlight* then reveals their card to everyone. The leader then collects the other *Mission* cards as normal.

The other team members must select their *Mission* card before seeing the revealed card.

It's important to select the target of *In the Spotlight* before any team members have selected their *Mission* card, because it could affect the choice they make. For example, if a Spy selects a *Fail* card before *In the Spotlight* is played, they would have to pick up their card to change it. That would certainly be very revealing. The intent of *In the Spotlight* is that the target player knows they will have to reveal their card before making their choice.

Comment: If any team members have already selected their Mission card before In the Spotlight is announced, another option would be to require everyone to pick up their mission card, whether they want to change it or not. That way, someone that does want to change their card can do so without giving themselves away.

Comment: The interesting aspect of this is that, unless the spies are able to win on the current mission, this will *effectively* force a spy to play a Success card if a spy is targeted by it. Although I suppose a well-coordinated spy team could throw one spy under the bus if it builds trust for another spy.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read the rules, In The Spotlight is played on a player after all players have played mission cards, before they are collected an shuffled.  After it is played, no player may change their card.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting confused with the "Keeping an Eye on You" card.